# How to run Privoxy from command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, privoxy

Privoxy won't start from command line (BATch file). Config file is specified.

```
D:\app\net\Privoxy_latest\privoxy.exe D:\app\net\Privoxy_latest\config.txt
```

Ending with:

`Fatal error: can't load re_filterfile '.\default.filter'`

I don't want run Privoxy as Windows service.

Answer (score 2):

you can go to the directory in batch using the CD command before using the START.

for x64 systems use:

```
cd "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Privoxy"
start /min "" Privoxy.exe config.txt
```

and for x86 os use:

```
cd "%PROGRAMFILES%\Privoxy"
start /min "" Privoxy.exe config.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit path of ***confdir*** in *config.txt* and point it to absolute path.

```
confdir D:\app\net\Privoxy_latest
```

So every other files (*.action, *.filter) specified in config.txt will be find correctly by Privoxy.

Comment: Or you can run _privoxy.lnk_ file ;)